# Insert if not exists in MongoDB without update

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `things` with documents like this one:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('60c8a023eedd25305625a461'),
  id: "1234",
  externalCode: 827
  name: "Thing 1"
}
```

Given an array of things with a random generated `id` (that doesn't correspond to `id`s in database), I need to insert them only when `externalCode` doesn't exist, **without change current database** `id`.

- If a thing "where externalCode = thing.externalCode" exists in database -> do nothing.
- Otherwise, insert thing with the generated `id`.

I have tried an update with `upsert: true`, but it changes the `id` field. I don't want that, but just insert if not exists.

Comment: Create a unique index for `externalCode` and be prepared for the insert operation to fail…!?

Comment: I don't think `upsert: true` will change `id` field's value see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jsy1vcwWBZ1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution and I want to share it with you.

The solution is `$setOnInsert` operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/